# Library Project - Android Studio : Error: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Im trying to add a Library Project (https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs) to my Android Studio project.

However I get the following build errors because my build is not able to reference the values in the Android-styled-dialog LibraryProject

```
android-apt-compiler: [NavigationDrawer] /Users/Jase/Downloads/NavigationDrawer/res/values-v11/themes_apptheme.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'DialogStyleLight'.

android-apt-compiler: [NavigationDrawer] /Users/Jase/Downloads/NavigationDrawer/res/values-v11/themes_apptheme.xml:30: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonBackgroundColorNormal'.

android-apt-compiler: [NavigationDrawer] /Users/Jase/Downloads/NavigationDrawer/res/values-v11/themes_apptheme.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonSeparatorColor'.

....
```

[image: android-styled-dialogs added as library project]

[image: The source code that has the error]

I don't really know anything about Gradle but I feel that I possibly need to tell the build to reference Android-styled-dialog. I don't know I'm completely lost...

---

PS: When I created a new android studio project with the demo project for Android-Styled-Dialogs it created the following mavin file... which I don't have in my other project - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8207108

I don't really know anything about Java build systems, please help

Comment: Despite the fact that you've got `build.gradle` files, it doesn't seem like your project is actually using it to do the builds. That android-apt-compiler message is something out of IntelliJ's builder.

Comment: Yes I added build.gradle myself in my lame attempt to get it working

Comment: If you want to use Gradle, you'll have to go whole-hog, and rework your project into a multi-module project structure with a top-level directory that has a `settings.gradle` file, directories underneath for your application and library modules, each with their own `build.gradle` files, and you'll have to reimport the project so it can pick it up and convert it to a Gradle-based project. If you continue using the IntelliJ builder, then I'm not as familiar with what you need to do -- check and make sure your application has a dependency on the library module via the Project Structure dialog.

Comment: Thanks Scott. This is beginning to become more complex than I hoped